# Python 3 Tkinter How to Refresh/Update Labels? Nim Game

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am unable to update the variables inside the labels even with the use of IntVar(). I am probably doing something chronically wrong. Tried to make a Nim game that updates the labels via changing the variables.

```
        # ministry of trade
        from tkinter import *
        import random

        # create root window
        root = Tk()

        # ministry of variables
        lst_choice = [1,2]
        lst_player = [1,2]
        player=random.choice(lst_player) #set random player
        playervar = StringVar()
        playervar.set(player)

        # Set the initial state
        state=7    # number of objects
        statevar = IntVar()
        statevar.set(state)

        winner=0
        winnervar = IntVar()
        winnervar.set(winner)

        move=0
        movevar = IntVar()
        movevar.set(move)

        def move1():
                                                                # move is assigned
                global statevar
                global playervar
                global winnervar

                if statevar.get()>0:
                    statevar.set(statevar.get() - 1)
                    print(statevar.get())                   #for testing only
                    return statevar

                if statevar.get()==0:                # check win status - win, lose, stalemate
                    winnervar.set(playervar.get())
                    print(winnervar.get())                  #for testing only
                    return winnervar

                if playervar.get()==1:            # switch players 2->1, 1->2 go back to the valid move line
                    playervar.set(2)
                    print(playervar.get())                  #for testing only
                    return playervar

                else:
                    playervar.set(1)
                    print(playervar.get())                  #for testing only
                    return playervar
                root.update_idletasks()
        def move2():
            return
        # Holy Roman Empire of the Widget Nation
        # electorate of Label

        labelAantalMunten = Label(root, text=("Aantal munten op stapel ",statevar.get()))    #state
        labelAantalMunten.pack() # orders to add the widget label to the root window and display it

        labelWelkSpeler = Label(root, text=("Nu is speler ",playervar.get()," aan de beurt"))  #player
        labelWelkSpeler.pack()

        labelWelkWinaar = Label(root, text=("Speler ",winnervar.get()," heeft gewonnen!"))  #winner
        labelWelkWinaar.pack()

        # electorate of Button
        button1 = Button(root, text="neem 1 steen", command=move1)
        button1.pack()

        button2 = Button(root, text="neem 2 stenen", command=move2)
        button2.pack()


        # start the main events loop    
        root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does "unable" mean? Why are you unable? Are you getting errors? Does the program crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example of what you should do to get the label display updated after every press of your button.

- You need to use `textvariable` instead of `text` in label.
- You need to declare a `StringVar` variable in your main code and have it updated in your function mov1.
- Note my example on how to get a string before passing it into your
  StingVar variable.

Have fun!

**Example code**

```
# ministry of trade
from tkinter import *
import random

# create root window
root = Tk()

# Set the initial state
state=7    # number of objects
statevar = IntVar()
statevar.set(state)

def move1():
                                # move is assigned
    global statevar

    if statevar.get()>0:
        print('statevar.get()>0')
        print(statevar.get())   #for testing only
        statevar.set(statevar.get() - 1)
        print(statevar.get())   #for testing only
        a = "Aantal munten op stapel " + str(statevar.get())
        print('a = {}'.format(a))
        text1.set(a)
        return statevar

a = "Aantal munten op stapel " + str(statevar.get())
text1=StringVar()
text1.set(a)
labelAantalMunten = Label(root, textvariable=text1)    #state
labelAantalMunten.pack() # orders to add the widget label to the root window and display it

# electorate of Button
button1 = Button(root, text="neem 1 steen", command=move1)
button1.pack()

# start the main events loop    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't _need_ to use `textvariable` and `StringVar` in order to update the label at run time. It's _a_ method but not the _only_ method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    labelWelkSpeler = Label(root, text=("Nu is speler ",playervar.get()," aan de beurt"))  #player
```

This gets the value of playervar ONCE (at the time you create the label), and builds the text of the label at that time.  (And probably doesn't build the text you actually wanted, as what you wrote is a tuple construction, not a string concatenation.)  It does not magically cause this code to be rerun every time that playervar changes!

The only way to get a Label to auto-update from a variable is to specify it as the `textvariable=` option, not `text=`.  The variable has to hold the entire text to be shown, so it's almost certainly going to be a StringVar, not an IntVar.  You would need to keep the player score in a separate variable (an ordinary Python variable, most likely), then .set() the StringVar yourself whenever it changes.